# What's the correct way to include the week day?

Tags: writing

To my understanding its correct to write date like `March 28, 2018`, for example:

```
On the afternoon of March 28, 2018 there was a visit to NASA.
```

Is it correct to write:

On the afternoon of Wednesday March 28, 2018 there was a visit to NASA.

What's the correct way to include the week day?

Comment: That's correct.  You should note that *visit* is a countable noun, so it has to be "**a** visit".

Comment: There are many ways of setting out dates. It would be equally acceptable to write: ...Wednesday 28 March 2018. Some people prefer this because it separates the digits. However, it's really just a matter of style and preference.

Comment: May I ask which way is more common, or sounds more natural?

Comment: @KcFnMi Which is more common or natural will also depend on which form of English you're speaking. American English tends to prefer "March 28", while most (all?) others will prefer "28 March".

Comment: (1) While discussing commas tends to start fights, it is common to set off distinct pieces of information using commas.  "...of March 28, 2018, ..." and "...Wednesday, March 28, 2018, ...."  (2) "On" is the wrong preposition.  It should be either "in" or "during."  You'll hear natives frequently use "on," but it is ungrammatical (how can you be "on" an afternoon or the time period of an afternoon?).  I prefer "during" because "afternoon" is a period of time.  "In" is acceptable, however, because it suggests being inside the period of time.

Comment: "On" is exactly the right preposition for that phrase, whether or not you are actually able to picture something being on top of a time period. "In the afternoon" alone is fine, but once you attach it to a day or date, it will naturally change to "On the afternoon of March 28," or "On Wednesday afternoon," etc. Out of curiosity, @JBH, do you also use a phrase like "in Wednesday"? I mean, how can you be __on__ a day of the week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of writing this.  "Wednesday, March 28th, 2018" is probably the most common and is universally (I think) acceptable.  "Wednesday 28 March 2018" is more formal and is usually only seen in legal documents.  "Wednesday the 28th" is common in spoken English when the month and year are obvious (often when making plans with friends).  Sometimes in written communication you'll see "Wednesday" abbreviated to "Wed." or "Wed"; this is perfectly acceptable in writing, but sounds strange in spoken English.  "Wednesday, March 28, 2018" is OK, but "28th" is preferred over "28".

Don't forget the comma after "Wednesday."

Note: I'm from the U.S., this may not be the case in the U.K. or other European countries.

Comment: Well, my elementary school textbooks would have said no to your first example; you were allowed to write *28th of March, 2018* or *March 28, 2018* but not *March 28th, 2018*. It's arbitrary, and I wouldn't be surprised if other textbooks said differently. But we labor under these sorts of prescriptive regimes, and out there, someone is going to knock off points mentally for seeing *March 28th, 2018* intentionally or not. I can't help but cringe at *different than*, for example, even though I know it's widely accepted.